# For what value of a does the curve have minimum and maximum points?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

For what value of a does the curve $$f(x)=5x^3 + ax^2 + 10x $$ have minimum and maximum points?
Multiple Choices are: A) |a|>15, B) |a|>$\sqrt{150}, C) |a|>1500,  D)|a|>\sqrt{30}, E) |a|>\sqrt{750} $
I calculated the derivative and got $$15x^2+2ax+10 = 0$$

Comment: This function is real-valued. When does there exist roots to the quadratic?

Comment: you use quadratic formula and solve for x, but i need to find a.

Comment: Yes, but you have roots to the quadratic when... the discriminant is non-negative. You have two if it is strictly positive. The answerer literally gives it away if you want to see it explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** $\triangle = (2a)^2 - 4\cdot 15\cdot 10 > 0$

Comment: i got it. 4a^2 > 600, a = $\sqrt{150}$